# select records from 3 tables with same column id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL query which will select records of a student within 3 tables that have the same column_I'd.

This is what I wrote but the the records selected are not accurate:

```
select 
   Nov_DEC_billing.*, 
   Nov_DEC_students_portfolio.*, 
   admission_form.academic_year 
from 
   Nov_DEC_billing, 
   Nov_DEC_student_portfolio, 
   admission_form 
where 
     Nov_DEC_billing.ID = Nov_DEC_student_portfolio.ID=admission_form.ID 
   AND 
     admission_form.Program ='Nov/dec'
```

I get a records selected alright but its not accurate. Please what's the right way to join 3 tables that share the same column_id.???

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result. Your "*not accurate*" is not descriptive at all. I also suggest using an explicit `JOIN` syntax. You will be able to see any missing conditions easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join tables something like this:

```
SELECT Nov_DEC_billing.*,
       Nov_DEC_students_portfolio.*,
       admission_form.academic_year 
FROM Nov_DEC_billing AS ndb,
  LEFT JOIN Nov_DEC_student_portfolio AS ndsp ON ndsp.ID=ndb.ID,
  LEFT JOIN admission_form AS af ON af.ID=ndb.ID
WHERE af.Program='Nov/dec'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` in your query

```
SELECT b.*, p.*, a.academic_year 
FROM Nov_DEC_billing b
JOIN Nov_DEC_student_portfolio p ON p.id = b.id
JOIN admission_form a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.Program='Nov/dec'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join all the tables to a single one.
What you will is join all the tables to a single one and then select from it.
Since you have 2 tables you should first join 2 and then join another one on the result.
See here [left join example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) for the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Nov_DEC_billing.ID=Nov_DEC_student_portfolio.ID=admission_form.ID
```

doesn't do what you expect. It takes the first part, `Nov_DEC_billing.ID=Nov_DEC_student_portfolio.ID` and evaluates it. If the values match, that part becomes a `1`, if they don't match, it becomes `0`. Then the `0` or the `1` is compared against `admission_form.ID`. That is very likely to give strange results.

So you'd have to split that into:

```
Nov_DEC_billing.ID=Nov_DEC_student_portfolio.ID
AND Nov_DEC_student_portfolio.ID=admission_form.ID
```

Or just use explicit join syntax, as the others already advised (and which I do too). That forces you to split this anyway.